# where to download CCured?

Tags: c, formal-verification

After reading a number of papers, I am trying to find the **CCured** sources (or even binaries) to try using it on my C source code.

However, all links appear to be dead. After some Googling, I am asking here. Could someone upload them (sources, docs, etc.) if you by any chance have a tarball lying on your hard drive?

EDIT: I also emailed one of the authors, but didn't get a response yet. Will try emailing others after a while.

(citation from the paper)

> CCured a program transformation system that adds type safety guarantees to existing C programs.  CCured attempts to verify statically that memory errors cannot occur, and it inserts run-time checks where static verification is insufficient.CCured extends C's type system by separating pointer types according to their usage, and it uses a surprisingly simple type inference algorithm that is able to infer the appropriate pointer kinds for existing C programs. CCured uses physical subtyping to recognize and verify a large number of type casts at compile time. Additional type casts are verified using run-time type information.

Comment: You might find it somewhere in the wayback machine, if it was ever released to the public.  It looks more like it was someone's doctoral project and only an online test version was ever released.  You can see it here [http://manju.cs.berkeley.edu/ccured](http://web.archive.org/web/20040401192158/http://manju.cs.berkeley.edu/ccured) through the wayback machine.

Comment: CCured is hardly the most modern memory safety tool available, and yes it was a research prototype.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_safety for alternatives.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20100701222844/http://hal.cs.berkeley.edu/ccured/distrib/ccured-1.3.5.tar.gz

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20110814124705/http://deputy.cs.berkeley.edu/ also check this. CCured is for legacy code, Deputy is for new code, the ideology is something like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better search for other projects in that general area, as the comments tell this has been mostly prototypes developed as a thesis and then abandoned. There might be a few in real use, perhaps the closest to what you are looking for are [LLVM](http://llvm.org)-based tools. Or something like [splint](http://splint.org). Or even instrumentation tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

Comment: Valgrind is not really comparable to CCured; but splint and llvm seem to be the right direction. I mailed all the authors and abandoned the effort))